# Trying to fill 2d array with specific values from a 1d array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to get values from a 1d array into a 2d array, but skipping over values I don't want.  In a previous method, i turned invalid values into -1s the the 1d array dimtoke, now I am trying to fill my 2d array, called dimensions, and trying to skip the invalid -1 and continue filling the array with the next valid value.

.

```
        // Taking valid line segments and putting them in 2d array.

        dimensions = new int[countLines][4];

        for (int i = 0; i < dimensions.length; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < dimensions[0].length; j++) {
              if(dimtoke[n] != -1){
                 dimensions[i][j] = dimtoke[n];
                 n++;
              }
              else
                 n++;       
           }
        }
```

my problem is that instead of filling the 2d array with the next valid value, it fills a 0 where i need my next value.

Comment: you need to decrement `j` in the else statement

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be that you are still incrementing the j variable when your found a -1. Change you code like this.

```
 dimensions = new int[countLines][4];

    for (int i = 0; i < dimensions.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < dimensions[0].length; j++) {
            if(dimtoke[n] != -1){
                dimensions[i][j] = dimtoke[n];
            }
        else
            j--;            
        }
           n++;
    }
```

I also moved the n++ out becuase you are calling it no matter the condition.